# SIGSEGV error when using AES_ctr128_encrypt for sockets

Tags: c, sockets, encryption, openssl

When i am trying to encrypt the data of the file using AES_ctr128_encrypt i am getting SIGBUS error. Here, I am using `read()` function to read the data from the file to the `bufptr[32k]`  in 32k chunks each time. For each chunk i want to encrypt only the part of data using `AES_ctr128_encrypt(bufptr+200, outdata, bytes_encrypt, &key, state.ivec, state.ecount, &state.num);` encrypt only the data desired and again send it to the server and there again decrypt it and add to the buffer. Can some one help me how to overcome this issue? Thanks in advance.

First client is able to send the file size to the server and when it has come to the `AES_ctr128_encrypt()` i am getting the the **Segmentation fault (core dumped)** and gdb says it is a SIGSEGV.

My header file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/sendfile.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/modes.h>
#include <openssl/crypto.h>
#define FAIL    -1
#define SEGMENT_SIZE 32768
#define j 10
#define OUT1 AES_BLOCK_SIZE
#define BYTES_ENCRYPT AES_BLOCK_SIZE
```

my client program

```
#include "headers.h"
#define FILE "/tmp/book"

struct ctr_state {
    unsigned char ivec[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
    unsigned int num;
    unsigned char ecount[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
};

int init_ctr(struct ctr_state *state, const unsigned char iv[8])
{
    /* aes_ctr128_encrypt requires 'num' and 'ecount' set to zero on the
     * first call. */
    state->num = 0;
    memset(state->ecount, 0, 16);

    /* Initialise counter in 'ivec' to 0 */
    memset(state->ivec + 16, 0, 16);

    /* Copy IV into 'ivec' */
    memcpy(state->ivec, iv, 16);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
size_t count;   
AES_KEY key;
unsigned char ckey[] =  "/home/nandan/aes.key"; 
unsigned char iv[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
struct ctr_state state;   

// validate proper usage
if (argc != 3)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <serverIP> <serverPort>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(-1);
}

// store the command line arguments 
char *server_ip = argv[1];
int server_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
// stores address of remote server to connect
struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
int fd, option;

fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (fd == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error creating socket\n");
    exit(-1);
}

memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));

server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_ip);
server_addr.sin_port = server_port;

if (connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting to server\n");
    exit(-1);
}

struct stat stats;
stat("/tmp/book", &stats);
int size = stats.st_size;
// send size of file to the client
send(fd, &size, sizeof(int),0);
printf("Written \n");
unsigned char outdata[OUT1];
in = open (FILE, O_RDONLY);
to_read = size;
char *bufptr = malloc(SEGMENT_SIZE);
  do
  {
   n = read (in, bufptr, SEGMENT_SIZE);
   if(n < 0)
   {  
    perror("Read Error:");
   }
   init_ctr(&state, iv);
   AES_ctr128_encrypt(bufptr+200, outdata, BYTES_ENCRYPT, &key, state.ivec, state.ecount, &state.num);
   memcpy(bufptr+200,outdata,BYTES_ENCRYPT);
   sending = send(fd, bufptr, n,0);
   to_read = to_read-n;
   } while (to_read != 0);  
close(fd);
}
```

my server program

```
#include "headers.h"
struct ctr_state {
    unsigned char ivec[16]; 
    unsigned int num;
    unsigned char ecount[16];
};
int init_ctr(struct ctr_state *state, const unsigned char iv[8])
{
    /* aes_ctr128_encrypt requires 'num' and 'ecount' set to zero on the
     * first call. */
    state->num = 0;
    memset(state->ecount, 0, 16);

    /* Initialise counter in 'ivec' to 0 */
    memset(state->ivec + 8, 0, 8);

    /* Copy IV into 'ivec' */
    memcpy(state->ivec, iv, 8);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

size_t count;    
AES_KEY key;   
unsigned char ckey[] =  "/home/nandan/aes.key";
unsigned char iv[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
struct ctr_state state;   
// validate proper usage
if (argc != 4)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage %s <serverBindIP> <serverBindPort> <CredentialsFilePath>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(-1);
}

int server;
char* ip = argv[1];
int port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
char* passwd_file = argv[3];
struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
clock_t start, end;
double cpu_time_used, timer = 0;
int server_fd, client_fd, result;
socklen_t length;

// Create an internet domain TCP socket
server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (server_fd == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create socket\n");
    exit(-1);
}

server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_port = port;
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);

// bind socket to an network interface
result = bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
if (result == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to bind socket\n");
    exit(-1);
}

// mark the socket used for incoming requests
listen(server_fd, 5);

// accept an incoming connection
printf("Waiting for incoming connection\n");
length = sizeof(client_addr);
client_fd = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &client_addr, &length);/* accept connection as usual */
if (client_fd == -1)
{
fprintf(stderr, "Unable to accept peer connection\n");
exit(-1);
}  
printf("Connection: %s:%d\n",inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
  int tmp = 0,i,size = 0;  // read file size first
  unsigned char outdata[OUT1]; 
  recv(client_fd, &size, sizeof(int),0);
  printf("%d \n", size);
  int bytes_read = 0;
  int to_read = size;
  printf("%d \n", size);
  FILE* out = fopen("/tmp/x1.pdf", "wb");
  char *buffer = malloc(SEGMENT_SIZE);
   do 
   {
     bytes_read = recv(client_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer),0);
     init_ctr(&state, iv);
     AES_ctr128_encrypt(buffer+200, outdata, BYTES_ENCRYPT, &key, state.ivec, state.ecount, &state.num);
     memcpy(buffer+200, outdata, BYTES_ENCRYPT);
     tmp = tmp + bytes_read;
    // save content to disk
     fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes_read, out);
   } while (tmp != size);
close(client_fd);         /* close socket */
return 0;
}
```

**edit1:** I don't want to encrypt all the data, i want to encrypt only the part of data in each chunk and see how useful it is.

Comment: Who is crashing? Server? Client?

Comment: In server `bytes_read = recv(client_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer),0);` should be `bytes_read = recv(client_fd, buffer, sizeof(SEGMENT_SIZE),0);`, `sizeof(buffer)` is the size of a pointer...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès  my client is crashing ..it is the one who is sending data first. and `sizeof(SEGMENT_SIZE)` i updated it .

Comment: GDB usually not only says _which_ signal it is, but also _where_ in the program it happened. Especially when you compile with `-ggdb`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is bad for different reasons:

- don't define struct inside function
- don't use local function (it is forbidden by the standard), `init_ctr`
- in the client, you send the `size` variable but it has not been declared
- in the server you used `sizeof(buffer)` in place of `SEGMENT_SIZE`
- use uppercased identifiers for #defined values, `bytes-encrypt`
- define your ivec and ecount to be of length AES_BLOCK_SIZE, do not use 16
- directly send `outdata`, don't copy it back to the buffer you read in
- why you only encrypt 16 bytes starting from `bufptr+200`?
- ...

May I suggest you to rewrite your code in a more clean way, it will be easier to find your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion i just modified my code to your suggestion i am getting `SIGSEGV`..any idea what to do..

Comment: Yes use a debugger to find what is the problem. You have serious problem with your memory management...

Comment: This is what my debugger says `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a7a9e0 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0`